# Hide slide-menu/nav bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Still learning ionic. I have a slide menu integrated into the app. The problem that I have is that I want to completely hide ionic nav bar and menu on top for my login view. I tried using ng-show to hide the nav bar based on whether or not current user is authenticated, but all it does is hide the content in the bar, but leaves empty nav bar container on top of the page.

I also tried using ng-if instead of ng-show, which does make the bar disappear completely, but when I need it to become visible again, the code produces an error: Cannot read property 'outerHtml' of null. I guess because the DOM object for the menu is not there anymore.

What is the best way to address this? Am I on the right path or is there a better way to show/hide

Comment: Here is a plunkr of what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work: 

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nxw7WmXlfcl25ZTggobS?p=preview

When I click on "Toggle Slide Menu", I want the whole top nav bar to disappear, not just its contents.

Comment: Never mind :) After digging for this for a whole day, found an answer 5 minutes after making this post. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hide-ion-nav-bar-for-single-page/1566 Looking for its equivalent for my bottom tabs bar.